# My computer randomly stops responding to keyboard input when I press keys

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

Several days ago, my computer has developed a problem. At seemingly random times of day it will stop responding to key presses. It can sometimes take up to 5 seconds for the computer to respond to input when this is happening but I can move the mouse and click without trouble. It is not limited to specific applications and it even blocks shortcut keys such as `Windows-D`

How can I find the cause of this problem? Could it be a running process that is blocking keyboard input?

<sub>Dell Precision LAPTOP, running Windows 7.</sub>

Comment: Whats a stroke touch/strike touch? does the keyboard freeze totally?

Comment: yes ! during 5s or less

Comment: When you press a key? (what key? Any key?) 5s before or after what?

Comment: when I press any key. (letter, figures, shift, capslock...) for example :

for the precedent 'example' word, I strike 'e' 'x' but nothing displayed... Then after 2s I retry and stroke 'e' 'x' 'a' 'm' 'p' 'l'... and it works.

Comment: Each time or randomly? Like if you tried to type something after that does it freeze again?

Comment: It seems randomly...

Comment: @Florian Do you experience this issue in Safe Mode?

Comment: Have you tried a different keyboard? Do you use text expansion apps such as AutoHotkey or PhraseExpress? Does your computer run in a virtual environment?

Answer (score 1):

**You may have a program running that is intercepting keyboard strokes** when you press a key.

You should run a full system scan according to the directions in this [community-approved virus detection and removal wiki](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now) and make sure there are no unauthorized programs running on your computer.

<sub>I experience a similar problem due to a screen dimming program that runs in the background. During certain times of the day when it is adjusting the screen, I cannot type.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have a game controller plugged in. If you do, it could turn upside down and wiggle the controller causing it to steal your curser. It happened to me several times before I figured it out and just unplugged my game controller and fixed the problem.